# How to make SqlConnection timeout more quickly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using an SQL connection string with SqlClient.SqlConnection and specifying Connection Timeout=5 in the string, but it still waits 30 seconds before returning failure.  How do I make it give up and return faster?  I'm on a fast local network and don't want to wait 30 seconds.  The servers that are not turned on take 30 seconds to fail.  This is just a quick utility program that's going to always run just on this local network.

**Edit**: Sorry if I was unclear.  I want the SqlConnection.Open to fail more quickly.  Hopefully that could be deduced from the fact that the servers I want to fail more quickly are turned off.

**Edit**: It seems that the setting only fails sometimes.  Like it knows the IP address of the server, and is using TCP/IP to talk to it (not local) but can't contact SQL Server at that address?  I'm not sure what the pattern is, but I don't see the problem when connecting locally with SQL Server stopped, and I don't see it when attempting to connect to a non-existent server.  I have seen it when attempting to contact a server where the Windows 2008 firewall is blocking SQL Server, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like all the cases that were causing long delays could be resolved *much* more quickly by attempting a direct socket connection like this:

```
foreach (string svrName in args)
{
   try
   {
      System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcp = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(svrName, 1433);
      if (tcp.Connected)
         Console.WriteLine("Opened connection to {0}", svrName);
      else
         Console.WriteLine("{0} not connected", svrName);
      tcp.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to {0}: {1}", svrName, ex.Message);
   }
}
```

I'm going to use this code to check if the server responds on the SQL Server port, and only attempt to open a connection if it does.  I thought (based on others' experience) that there would be a 30 second delay even at this level, but I get a message that the machine "actively refused the connection" on these right away.

**Edit:** And if the machine doesn't exist, it tells me that right away too.  No 30-second delays that I can find.

**Edit:** Machines that were on the network but are not turned off still take 30 seconds to fail I guess.  The firewalled machines fail faster, though.

**Edit:** Here's the updated code. I feel like it's cleaner to close a socket than abort a thread:

```
static void TestConn(string server)
{
   try
   {
      using (System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
      {
         IAsyncResult async = tcpSocket.BeginConnect(server, 1433, ConnectCallback, null);
         DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
         do
         {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (async.IsCompleted) break;
         } while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds < 5);
         if (async.IsCompleted)
         {
            tcpSocket.EndConnect(async);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection succeeded");
         }
         tcpSocket.Close();
         if (!async.IsCompleted)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Server did not respond");
            return;
         }
      }
   }
   catch(System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Update 2*
I suggest rolling your own timeout.  Something like this:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SqlServerIsRunning("Server=foobar; Database=tempdb; Integrated Security=true", 5));
        Console.WriteLine(SqlServerIsRunning("Server=localhost; Database=tempdb; Integrated Security=true", 5));
    }

    private static bool SqlServerIsRunning(string baseConnectionString, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        bool result;

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(baseConnectionString + ";Connection Timeout=" + timeoutInSeconds))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(TryOpen);
            ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            thread.Start(new Tuple<SqlConnection, ManualResetEvent>(sqlConnection, manualResetEvent));
            result = manualResetEvent.WaitOne(timeoutInSeconds*1000);

            if (!result)
            {
                thread.Abort();
            }

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void TryOpen(object input)
    {
        Tuple<SqlConnection, ManualResetEvent> parameters = (Tuple<SqlConnection, ManualResetEvent>)input;

        try
        {
            parameters.Item1.Open();
            parameters.Item1.Close();
            parameters.Item2.Set();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Eat any exception, we're not interested in it
        }
    }
}
```

*Update 1*

I've just tested this on my own computer using this code:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=tempdb; Integrated Security=true;Connection Timeout=5");
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to open connection with {0} second timeout, starting at {1}.", con.ConnectionTimeout, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully opened connection at {0}.", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SqlException raised at {0}.", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
    }
}
```

and it obeys the `Connection Timeout` value in the connection string.  This was with .NET 4 against SQL Server 2008 R2.  Admittedly, it's a localhost connection which may give different results but it means I can't replicate the problem.

I can only suggest trying a similar chunk of code in your network environment and seeing if you continue to see long timeouts.

*Old (incorrect) answer*
I incorrectly thought the `ConnectionTimeout` property was settable, but it isn't.

Try setting [SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) instead of using the connection string.

Comment: I'm hitting a very odd pattern here. The timeout seems to work when I connect to my local system with SQL Server stopped.  It seems to work when I try to connect to a non-existent server.  But it doesn't seem to work when I try to connect to a server that exists, but has the firewall blocking SQL and/or doesn't have SQL Server installed.

Comment: An interesting thread on this issue here: http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/topic48533.aspx.  I suggest implementing your own timeout mechanism - spin off a thread to try doing the open and kill it if it hasn't succeeded within your desired timeout period.

Comment: Wow, what a pain.  Is it safe/clean to just abort a thread like that?  I wonder if I would get different results simply trying to open port 1433 directly.

Comment: I get similar results when I try telnet host 1433 from a command prompt.  If I try to go to a non-existent server, it times out after a couple seconds.  If I try to go to a server that exists, but doesn't allow 1433, it hangs for 30 seconds.  It's starting to make sense now.  But unfortunately that just confirms that the only way around this is your solution of aborting the thread... still be interested to know how clean/safe that is, though.

Comment: I'm not certain but I don't think it's "unsafe" to abort the thread.  Ultimately, all resources will be cleaned up when the application terminates so you won't leave any connections hanging.  You might find that the thread doesn't actually shut down until the "real" timeout occurs which may prevent the application from shutting down promptly but this approach would at least allow you to test multiple servers in quick succession.

Comment: Suddenly all the comments that I saw in the devnewsgroups thread don't make sense -- don't agree with the reality I'm seeing in my tests.  When I try to establish a direct socket connection, it comes back with success or failure right away in all the tests I could perform.

Comment: Oops, I guess the machines that are completely turned off still take 30 seconds to fail.  But the machines with a firewall were failing much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The Command Timeout and the Connection Timeout are two different things.

[SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) is "the time (in seconds) to wait for a connection to open. The default value is 15 seconds." Thats only used when you call SqlConnection.Open().

The SqlCommand.CommandTimeout does what you want to do.

Comment: SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout is what you want

Comment: @GBK You can set the timeout on the connection string then. You can use a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to parse and modify the connection string before you pass it to the connection object.