# Database Unavailable in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I've written a windows service(c#) using Entity Framework 5 for data access against SQL Server.  I need my service to cope with the database being unavailable as will happen from time to time, and so want to explicitly handle this exception.

Thing is, I can't work out where to capture this exception, and how to identify it.  I will have other DB errors I need to capture e.g. PK violations so can't do a generic SQLException check on SaveChanges(). On the other hand I can't wrap the connection open(as I would have pre-EF) in a try catch as I've left all that to Entity Framework.

Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance - Andy

Comment: Show your code which you have implemented..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test to see if Entity Framework is connected to something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080360/test-to-see-if-entity-framework-is-connected-to-something)

Answer (score 0):

imho the unavailability may occurs at any time, even after a successfull connection but before a commit or during a read.

So you have to catch the exception at highest level and in your catch block try to connect (may be asynchronously as the connection timeout may be significant). The test may be done as disclosed in the post cited in a comment [To see if entity Framework is connected to something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080360/test-to-see-if-entity-framework-is-connected-to-something)