# Entity Framework returns empty list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-config, mdf

When I try to select All items in a list I got an empty list.

This is my `Business.Classification` class, where I call `ToList()`

```
public class Classification
{
    private DatabaseContext db;

    public Classification()
    {
        if (db == null)
            db = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    public int getClassification()
    {

        using (db)
        {
            List<Classification> a = db.ClassificationContext.ToList();

            return a.Count;
        }
    }

}
```

This is My Model class:

```
[Table("Classification")]
public class Classification
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column]
    public Guid ClassificationId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string ClassificationName { get; set; }

}
```

Here goes my Context class:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Classification> ClassificationContext { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the app Config file of my Business project:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You have records in the DB?

Comment: try other table to see is your connection working.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yes, I have imported to SQL server and I've checked that

Comment: @user3754008 I've used this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080360/test-to-see-if-entity-framework-is-connected-to-something to test the connection and It's Ok

Comment: try to change your Classification to other name. It might be issue because you have same class name as your table class name.

Comment: @user3754008 Just tried that, didn't work

Comment: try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

your connection string might cost this issue.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, might be an issue with the way you use the context

`

```
using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext())
{
 return context.tablename.tolist().count;  
}
```

`

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your conn string