# SQL Connection Not Timing Out Quickly When Network Cable Unplugged

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclient, connection-timeout

First I unplug my network cable.

Then I try to connect to SQL Server from within C# using an SqlClient.SqlConnection object and a connection string that either does not specify a connection timeout (and thus defaults to 15 seconds): `Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MYSERVER;Database=MYDB"`

or a connection string that does specify a timeout, even shorter at 5 seconds: `"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MYSERVER;Database=MYDB;Connect Timeout=5"`

Either way, the call to `connection.Open` returns after 42 seconds with my timeout error.  If I plug my network cable back in earlier, I can provoke an error sooner.  Why is the connection timeout having no effect?  Is this documented somewhere?  Is there a way around it?

Comment: My guess is that it is looking for a SQL timeout based on a found SQL box (a pure SQL timeout).  A network timeout is separate.  You could ping before you try and connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connect Timeout` applies ONLY when it is able to resolve the server and waits for a connection.

As per MSDN also, `Connect Timeout` is the length of time (in seconds - default 15) to wait for a connection to the server before terminating the attempt and generating an error.

Note:
5 seconds is too less for networking hardwares to detect the network is available or not. It should not be less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Is there any way to time out in less than the 42 seconds I'm seeing if there's no network connection?

Comment: You can ping the ip of sql server machine before attempting connection. Refer http://www.makhaly.net/Blog/11

Comment: I suppose that would work, but I don't really want to ping every time, and even if I did there's still a race condition.  If there were some way to set a true timeout, that would be nice.  Maybe they just don't have that functionality for an SqlConnection though.

Comment: @user12861, I think you must post a new question regarding your new queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619347/how-to-make-sqlconnection-timeout-more-quickly seems to indicate there's no really good solution, just workarounds susceptible to race conditions.