# Is SQL Server available

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET to create a simple application which will test if a variety of SQL Server are available online.

I have the code below, but the timeout is not working and it simply waits forever rather than throwing a timeout error. I have put breakpoints in and, as this is in an loop of IP's, it never progresses if the IP being checked is unavailable.

```
 Dim data As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DatabaseIP;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False".Replace("DatabaseIP", IP))

Try
    data.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim stophere As String = ""
    TextBox1.Text += IP + vbNewLine
End Try
```

Comment: Why are you naming `data` to a SqlConnection?

Comment: Because that's what I wanted to call it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make SqlConnection timeout more quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619347/how-to-make-sqlconnection-timeout-more-quickly)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  My issue is that the timeout is NOT occurring., rather than how to make it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

`Connect Timeout=15` is not correct, try it with `Connection Timeout=15`

Comment: I've made this change and it has produced no effect on the outcome

Comment: after crating your sqlconnection check that the timeout is set correctly ex: Debug.WriteLine("ConnectionTimeout: {0}", data.ConnectionTimeout)

Comment: Yes.  This shows as 15.  There is all probability that the IP / Database may not be reachable.  I'm unsire if this makes any difference/

Answer (score 0):

To connect with Database, following code is enough,

```
Dim data As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DatabaseIP;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=;")
```

Comment: And this will use the default timeout settings, which is NOT actually happening.  My question is as to WHY the timeout is not working, and how to get the connection request to timeout and indicate that the DB is not accessible.